# Applet error: The method add(String, Component) in the type Container is not applicable

Tags: java, eclipse, applet

I am trying to learn a source code of a tutorial I saw on the Internet (looks somewhat outdated). In the Applet class, I get an error from add(string, Component) part.

The method add(String, Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (String, ChatClient)

Why can't I use add in below code?

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ClientApplet extends Applet
{

    public void init() {

        String host = getParameter( "host" );
        int port = Integer.parseInt( getParameter( "port" ) );
        ChatClient client = new ChatClient(host,port);
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
        add(client, "Center" );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to change

add(client, "Center" );

to

add(client, BorderLayout.CENTER)

Comment: hmm it still has red line under add. The method add(String, Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (ChatClient, String)

Comment: *"`not applicable for the arguments (ChatClient, String)`"* The code is trying to add an instance of an applet to another instance of the same applet.  That won't work.  BTW - that code would not compile.   For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).